# Getting different results with different approaches in probability

Tags: probability, combinations

I recently came across a question where $2$ out of $52$ playing cards were drawn at random and I had to find the probability of the first one being a spade and the second a diamond.

My approach of solving this sum was that in first attempt the probability of getting a spade was $\frac14$ and in second attempt the probability of getting a diamond would be $\frac{13}{51}$ (since we already chose a spade in our 1st attempt) so the probability would be $\frac14 \times \frac{13}{51}=\frac{13}{204}$.

Whereas my teacher solved it by telling that the total no. of ways in which $2$ cards can be drawn is $\binom{52}{2}$ i.e. $1326$ and the total no. ways in which spade and diamond can be selected is $\binom{13}{1} \times \binom{13}1 $i.e. $169$, so the probability would be $\frac{169}{1326}=\frac{13}{102}$.

I feel that both methods are correct but why do they differ in the result that they give?

Comment: The wording of the question matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher's method seems wrong, as what (s)he is calculating is the probability of getting one spade and one diamond, rather than first spade and second diamond. Picking first position for spade will add that extra factor of 1/2.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is correct.

$\binom{52}{2}$ doesn't take the ordering into consideration. It doesn't distinguish (spade ace then diamond A) from (diamond A and then spade ace). The total number of ways $2$ cards can be drawn is $2 \binom{52}{2}$ if we care about the ordering.

Answer (score 3):

Both methods are correct, they just answer *different* questions.   As copper hat commented, wording matters.

What is the probability for drawing two cards so the first is a spade and the second is a diamond?   That is $\tfrac {13}{52}\tfrac {13}{51}$ or $13/204$ as you said.

What is the probbility for drawing two cards so one is a spade and the other is a diamond?   That will be $\binom {13}1^2/\binom{52}2$ or $13/102$ as your teacher suggested.

So *one* of you is correctly answering *the wrong question*.   That is all.